# MongoError when using mongoose with nw.js application

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am developing a nw.js application and trying to use mongoose - the mongodb vesrion of node.js as database.

I have connected the mongoose as,

```
 var mongoose = require('./mongoose');
  mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/myDBName');
  var db = mongoose.connection;
  db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
  db.once('open', function () {
         alert();
   });
```

where mongoose folder located at the root folder of my project, but it given the following error.

`message: "connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017"
name: "MongoError"`

I also tried with `mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/myDBName');`and for require statement `var mongoose = require('mongoose');` but both are  of no use. Where i'm missing exactly?

Comment: can you access mongodb through `mongo` client?

Comment: Your codes seems well, I guess this issue maybe in the mongod server side...

Comment: it gives `Tue Jan 26 10:42:58.341 Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:145
exception: connect failed` in terminal

Comment: Your mongo server start on `127.0.0.1:27017` or bind your local ip?